# Counting records that have count(column) > 2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a CustomerData table with the following attributes:
FirstName, LastName, DateofBirth, ID, Location

I am trying to write a query that pulls the first name, last name, date of birth, and IDNumber of users who belong to more than one location.

I tried the following code but I am getting an error about aggregates needing a group by clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM CustomerData
WHERE Count(Location) > 2
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [HAVING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx):

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, DateofBirth, ID, Count(Location)
FROM CustomerData
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, DateofBirth, ID
HAVING Count(Location) > 2
```

HAVING is basically a `WHERE` that allows you to use aggregate functions.

Comment: Thank you, I also used a DISTINCT in my COUNT clause to count distinct locations. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a sub-query:

```
select c1.FirstName, c1.LastName, c1.DateofBirth, c1.ID, c2.CntLocation
from CustomerData c1
left join
(
    SELECT Count(Location) CntLocation, location
    FROM CustomerData
    group by location
) c2
    on c1.location = c2.location
WHERE CntLocation > 2
```